# WCF Show/Hide Methods For User Groups

Tags: wcf, authorization

I have a wcf web service and there are two types of users that will use this service.Service methods need to be different for each user group. In other words, User group A should not see service methods that belong to user group B. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there any overlap at all in the services used by group A and group B?

Comment: Yes, there is. Some methods are common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you interested in physically hiding operations from the group? If so you'll need to host separate services which define only those operations. In this scenario, common operations will need to be replicated or refactored out into another service.

If you're only interested in restricting access to certain operations based on group membership then have a look at role-based or claim-based authorization. I am assuming authentication has already been done.